# S3 Versioning: Is just file level versioning possible and does it recognized file formats for intelligent diff calculation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, document-versioning

S3 Provides bucket level versioning if am right. But if I need versioning for only few particular files in a bucket, is it possible.
Further does it apply any binary/text diff strategy (like git, svn) to save these versions of files or it just saves each version in it's entirety.

Comment: Why does it matter how the bucket stores the different versions? Meaning, why do you care if it makes complete snapshots or use some form of diff/delta compression?

Comment: "The versioning state applies to all (never some) of the objects in that bucket." - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html 
"Each version of an object is the entire object; it is not just a diff from the previous version." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AddingObjectstoVersioningEnabledBuckets.html

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - "why do you care..." - because you pay for each stored object: "Thus, if you have three versions of an object stored, you are charged for three objects." - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AddingObjectstoVersioningEnabledBuckets.html

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, diff/delta is important because cumulative size matters with large files.

Comment: @Joe Exactly, so if you're charged as though they're separate, does it matter if amazon uses compression behind the scenes?